# What's wrong with this Android program?

Tags: android, textview, android-edittext

I am writing a test application which consists of:
2 buttons
1 Edittext
1 Textview

The first button "Random" writes a random name both in the EditText box and the TextView
(I have a class called RandomName which returns a string with a random name)

The second button "print" writes whatver is in the EditText into the TextView

The program crashes when I run it and i can't figure out why. Any help would be appreciated

Layout image here: http://img824.imageshack.us/img824/3046/rndname.jpg

```
public class RandomNameTesteActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}


public EditText nomeEdt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
public String nomeStr = nomeEdt.toString();
public TextView nomeTest = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);



public void onClick(View v) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      switch(v.getId())
      {
      case R.id.button1:
       //Put random name in EditText box and in TextView
          RandomName RndName = new RandomName();
          String rndNameStr = RndName.getName();  
          nomeTest.setText(rndNameStr);


      break;
      case R.id.button2:
       //Print whatever is in EditText box to TextView      
         nomeTest.setText(nomeStr);
      break;
      }
     }
```

}

EDIT: CHANGED CODE TO THE FOLLOWING: (it doesnt crash anymore but it doesnt work, as in the buttons do nothing)

```
 public class RandomNameTesteActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
EditText nomeEdt;
TextView nomeTest;
String nomeStr;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    nomeEdt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    nomeStr = nomeEdt.toString();
    nomeTest = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
}






public void onClick(View v) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      switch(v.getId())
      {
      case R.id.button1:
       //Put random name in EditText box and in TextView
          RandomName RndName = new RandomName();
          String rndNameStr = RndName.getName();  
          nomeTest.setText(rndNameStr);


      break;
      case R.id.button2:
       //Print whatever is in EditText box to TextView      
         nomeTest.setText(nomeStr);
      break;
      }
     }
```

}

Comment: much more interested in the layout xml than a screencap of what it's supposed to look like ;)

Comment: just to add to the above comment - Where are your button1 and button2? Do you assign an OnClickClistener to the buttons. Please be elaborate with your questions and descriptions. Only then, people here will be able to help you.

Comment: Problem solved, the click listeners were missing indeed. I'm sorry about the question being incomplete. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is with the following lines:

```
public EditText nomeEdt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
public String nomeStr = nomeEdt.toString();
public TextView nomeTest = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

Change this to

```
public EditText nomeEdt;
public TextView nomeTest;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
nomeEdt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
nomeStr = nomeEdt.toString();
nomeTest = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
}
```

Try that and see if it fixes your issue.  You can't look up your other views until you have set the contentview.

Also it helps if you post the stacktrace when asking a question

Comment: I edited my code to the following, it doesnt crash anymore but it doesnt work - the buttons do nothing:

"Question edited****"

Comment: You haven't set an onclick listener for your button, unless you did that in your view.xml(which you haven't posted).  look here for more information.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html

Comment: Yes, the Click Listeners were missing indeed. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare your `EditText` and `TextView` in the `onCreate()` method not in the body of your class. That is because you can't call findViewById() if you don't have called `setContentView()` which is in your `onCreate()` method.

Comment: on a semantic note, declaration and assignment are two separate things. they **can** be declared before setContentView, they **can't** be assigned a value from findViewById before setContentView has been called.

Answer (score 1):

you can declare your ui elements as members, but you can't give them values with the "find view by id"-method at declaration. this is because they don't exist until after you've called "set content view". so at declaration, do:

```
public EditText nomeEdt;
```

and so on, and in onCreate, after your call to setContentView, do:

```
nomeEdt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
```

and so on :)

Comment: @AngeloTiberiodeCarvalho must have the layout file main.xml too

Answer (score 1):

You need to set onClickListeners for you buttons.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);


nomeEdt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
nomeStr = nomeEdt.toString();
nomeTest = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(this);
findViewById(R.id.button2).setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

Comment: Yes, the Click Listeners were missing indeed. Thank you all.